# dplyr Update a cell in a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <-data.frame(x=c(1:5),y=c(letters[1:5]))
```

Let's say I want to modify the last row,

```
update.row<-filter(df,x==5) %>% mutate(y="R")
```

How do I update this row into the data.frame ?
The only way, I found albeit a strange way is to do an 
anti-join and append the results.

```
df <-anti_join(df,update.row,by="x") %>%
     bind_rows(update.row)
```

However, it seems like a very inelegant way to achieve a simple task.
Any ideas are much appreciated...

Comment: `df <- df %>% mutate(y = replace(as.character(y), x == 5, "R"))`

Comment: `df$y[df$x==5] <- "R"` and be done with it.

Comment: Here is a minor alternative to the solution by @Jota, `df %>% mutate(y = ifelse(x == 5, 'R', as.character(y)))`. The `as.character` is needed here because `y` is a factor.

Comment: @thelatemail -1 not enough dplyr

Comment: @Jota solution was good enough..

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`, we can assign (`:=`) the value to the rows where `i` is TRUE.  It is very efficient as the assignment is done in place.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[x==5, y:="R"]
df
#   x y
#1: 1 a
#2: 2 b
#3: 3 c
#4: 4 d
#5: 5 R
```

As the OP mentioned about the last row, a more general way is

```
setDT(df)[.N, y:= "R"]
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned, if we want to replace any row just mention the row index in `i` i.e. in this case `5`.

```
setDT(df)[5, y:="R"]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are insistant on `dplyr`, perhaps

```
df <-data.frame(x=c(1:5),y=c(letters[1:5]))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(y = as.character(y)) %>%
    mutate(y = ifelse(row_number()==n(), "R", y))

#  x y
#1 1 a
#2 2 b
#3 3 c
#4 4 d
#5 5 R
```