# How to change the values of a specific cell on a table based off user inputs? R Shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have the following shiny app. My goal is to have users select the column and row they wish to alter and replace it with new text.

I am trying to this with dplyr and using this question as a resource. [Modify a single cell value in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821467/modify-a-single-cell-value-in-dplyr)

Although for some reason in my shiny app I can't get it to work?

The Column input identifies the column and then the row number identifies the row to alter. And then the last input is where you can enter the new values.

Here is a screenshot of my desired output

[image]

Code

```
library(shiny)
library(gt)

ui <- fluidPage(# App title ----
                titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
                
                # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
                sidebarLayout(
                  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                  sidebarPanel(
                    uiOutput("colControls"),
                    numericInput(
                      "AnnotateNum1",
                      label = "Select Row Numbers to Annotate",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 1000000,
                      value = 1
                    ),
                    textInput("AnnotateText1", label = "Enter Annotation Number", value = "")
                    
                  ),
                  
                  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
                  mainPanel(# Display Graph
                    gt_output("gt_table"))
                  
                ))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  data <- reactive({
    d <- gt::gtcars %>% head(10)
    d
  })
  
  # Choose Column to change
  output$colControls <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "cols",
      "Filter Columns",
      choices = data() %>% colnames(),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  
  # new_data <- reactive({
  #   if (is.null(input$cols)) {
  #     data()
  #   } else {
  #     data() %>%
  #       mutate(input$cols = ifelse(
  #         row_number() == {input$AnnotateNum1},
  #         {input$AnnotateText},
  #         input$cols
  #       )) }
  #   
  # })
  # 
  # 
  output$gt_table <- render_gt({
    z <- #new_data() %>% 
      data()
      gt()
    z
  })
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column name is a string you need to use some non-standard evaluation in `dplyr` -

```
library(shiny)
library(gt)

ui <- fluidPage(# App title ----
                titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
                
                # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
                sidebarLayout(
                  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                  sidebarPanel(
                    uiOutput("colControls"),
                    numericInput(
                      "AnnotateNum1",
                      label = "Select Row Numbers to Annotate",
                      min = 0,
                      max = 1000000,
                      value = 1
                    ),
                    textInput("AnnotateText1", label = "Enter Annotation Number", value = "")
                    
                  ),
                  
                  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
                  mainPanel(# Display Graph
                    gt_output("gt_table"))
                  
                ))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  data <- reactive({
    d <- gt::gtcars %>% head(10)
    d
  })
  
  # Choose Column to change
  output$colControls <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "cols",
      "Filter Columns",
      choices = data() %>% colnames(),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  
  new_data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$cols) || input$AnnotateText1 == "") {
      data()
    } else {
      data() %>%
        mutate(!!input$cols := ifelse(
          row_number() == input$AnnotateNum1,
          input$AnnotateText1,
          .data[[input$cols]]
        )) }

  })


  output$gt_table <- render_gt({
    z <- new_data() %>% 
    gt()
    z
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]